# How to properly set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, plist

I have had an app rejected by Apple stating that I need to implement `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in my info.plist due to my app requiring a camera flash. I understand the issue but I am not sure how to properly set this key. Do I create `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` as a dictionary or array? and camera-flash as a bool or string? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add this text to your app's Info.plist file:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>camera-flash</string>
</array>
```

You only need a dictionary if some of the capability requirements need to be false.

Important note from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities):

> For app updates, you can only maintain or relax capability requirements. Submitting an update with added requirements would prevent some customers who previously downloaded your app from running the update.

Comment: For more information, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1397/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode -> Info(info.plist)

add key
UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

in this key add:

camera-flash

still-camera