# Add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to info.plist using Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a preset entry that can be selected for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities(most standard keys are in a pull down list)? Or do we need to manually add an entry and change it to a dictionary of keys with boolean values?

I tried something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question [How to properly set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765837/how-to-properly-set-uirequireddevicecapabilities) provides the answer you are looking for as well as a link to the proper spot in the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1397/_index.html if you have any further questions. Hope that solves it. - Rich