# Bluetooth Low Energy as an iOS device requirement?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does anyone know how to add Bluetooth Low Energy as a device requirement to only allow the iOS app to be available on devices with Bluetooth LE?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to add the `bluetooth-le` option to your [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765837/how-to-properly-set-uirequireddevicecapabilities) key in your info.plist file.