# Is it possible to publish games developed with spritekit & swift for iphone5 & 6 only

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, sprite-kit

Currently, I have a game made with swift & spritekit that supports iphone 5 & 6 screen size perfectly, however, the position of the nodes are not well positioned for ipads, iphones 4s and below. Is it posible to publish ios games for only specific device or should it support old iphones and ipads ? I do understand that in order to support all device sizes I should use view.bounds but since I set the GameScene with `(size: CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334))` and `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`,and I want to keep it this way.  But if I set a specific size will my app have a higher possibility for rejection ? I really want to support only iphones 5 and above. I would love to here from you.

Comment: Your app has to run on iPad. You can make it iPhone only, but then it has to run at the iPhone 4s resolution in compatibility mode. I would suggest you make it a universal app and work to make it look good on the 1024x768 points screens.

Comment: Why does it have to run on iPads? He has already stated that his hard coding of sizes (and presumably carefully calibrated physics and movement within that aspect ratio) means it's only good on the aspect ratio of the iPhone 5(S) and iPhone 6.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exactly do what you are asking, but you can specify certain UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in your info.plist.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1

In this way, say you claim that your app requires metal, well only iPhone 5s and higher support that.  Of course I realize you want to start with iPhone 5.

Unfortunately there isn't a required device capability that distinguishes iPhone 5 from 4s on that list.    4s and higher, 5s and higher, would be possible.  but not 5 and higher.

Comment: Thank you sir! Does it mean that if I set the requirement of metal ,I will be able to run on only iphone 5 and higher and  set  the GameScene like (size: CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334)) ?     But the embarassing part is I don't know how to set the metal even though I've seen the link.  If only apple had some easy example like on android developers site it would help a noob like me.

Comment: iPhone 5s and higher.  Here is another stackoverflow post on setting the requirement in info.plist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765837/how-to-properly-set-uirequireddevicecapabilities

Comment: Your app has to run on iPad. You can make it iPhone only, but then it has to run at the iPhone 4s resolution in compatibility mode. I would suggest you make it a universal app and work to make it look good on the 1024x768 points screens.